# English expression "pear shaped"

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “everything's gone pear-shaped” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30948/what-does-everythings-gone-pear-shaped-mean)

What is the origin and meaning of "pear shaped", as in "this situation is about to go pear shaped"

Comment: There's quite a good discussion in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pear-shaped)

Answer (score 4):

The meaning is simply "gone wrong".

As to the origin: nobody knows.

There is a short discussion of it on the normally reliable World Wide Words [here](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-pea2.htm)

Comment: I don't think it means *just* "gone wrong", I think usually implies "gone wrong in a very bad way, and very quickly".

Comment: Possibly. The OED says "to go (badly) wrong, " - with the "badly" in brackets.

Comment: I have never seen it used for things that went "mildly badly". It is not quite as bad as things going "apocalypticly badly" but it's usually a step firmly in that direction. I think I even saw a reference to something going pear-shaped, and using the exponential curve of the pear to illustrate *why* the situation was *pear*-shaped, instead of, say *apple*-shaped (I wish I could remember where I saw/heard that).

Answer (score 1):

In BE the usual meaning of "pear-shaped" is simply that something has gone wrong; there is little implication of degree. I have always understood the phrase to refer to a circle (as in the form of a wheel) becoming distorted into uselessness.